# Thunderbird doesn't show reminder popup for events for tasks

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, plugin, calendar

I am using Thunderbird version 52.7.0, on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Xenial.

I have a hard time to figure out why I don't get any *Reminder Popup* for events or tasks. Even though I have setup my Lightning as follow:

[image: Lightning setup]

I also checked *Show Reminders* in *Menu Edit → Calendar Properties…*, but still I don't get reminder.

I did a test that, if I am the Organizer of event then I got a reminder. For the event I get invited, I don't get reminder.

Is it that the case, that only the owner of event gets reminder? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What kind of calendar (source) do you use in Lightning? Local files? ICal? CalDav? Something else? Since you speak of “owner[s]”, who owns the events and how is ownership determined? Just to eliminate another potential source of error: how exactly do you set reminders on events or tasks?

Comment: I guess its local files, because we use it for internal in company. About "owner", I mean Organizer / Creator of the event. As I said in my post, if I am Organizer, then I get reminder. And for events I get invited, I don't get reminder. Please forgive me if it is confusing.

Comment: If you use local files (i. e. Sqlite databases that can only be in use by one client application at a time even on a file system shared over a network) and no network calendar service, how do you enter events into the calendar that you do not create yourself? Import from e-mails with attached calendar data? In what format? On my system Lightning reminds me of events imported from invitation e-mails sent by Google Calendar (at least into calendars based on local database files or ICal services).

Comment: I am not familiar with this, our IT department configured everything, and when i got my work station, Thunderbird and calendar are aleady there. I just checked the location of calendar, it is _moz-storage-calendar://_, don't know if it is any help. About events, I just go to Calendar, there are Event and Task buttons where I can create event or task

Comment: If your IT department set this up it may be helpful to inquire with them. Even if they won't solve the client-side problem (in a reasonable time) they can provide worthwhile input on the set-up in general. You could ask them to edit the info into the question (with an appropriate note for reviewers) and then approve the edit suggestion yourself.